# Why length of encrypted numerical value is different?

Tags: ruby, encryption

I encrypted numerical value as following.

```
> secret = Sestrong textcureRandom::hex(128)
> encryptor = ::ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.new(secret, cipher: 'aes-256-cbc')

> message1 = 1
> message1.size
=> 8
> message1.class
=> Fixnum
> encrypt_message1 = encryptor.encrypt_and_sign(message1)
> encrypt_message1.length
=> 110

> message2 = 10000
> message2.size
=> 8
> message2.class
=> Fixnum
> encrypt_message2 = encryptor.encrypt_and_sign(message2)
> encrypt_message2.length
=> 110
```

Above result is expected result.
Because, class of number which is less than 4611686018427387903 is Fixnum, and size of Fixnum is 8 byte.
In addition, block size of AES is 128bit(16 byte).
8 byte < 16 byte.
So, both length of encrypted value of 1 and 10000 is same.

But, following case, Length of encrypted value is different.

```
> message3 = 1000000000000000000000000000
> message3.size
=> 12
> message3.class
=> Bignum
> encrypt_message3 = encryptor.encrypt_and_sign(message3)
> encrypt_message3.size
=> 138
```

1000000000000000000000000000 is Bignum,but this size is 12 and less than 16(block size of AES).
So, I expected that length of encrypted value is same to that of Fixnum.
But, these are different...

Why are these different?

Comment: Try printing the class name of the encrypted message...

Comment: I tried to print class.

    > encrypt_message1.class
    => String
    > encrypt_message3.class
    => String

Comment: Then there's your answer :) ie - the size of a number is merely the size of register that he number is stored in, but the size of a string is how many characters are in the string...

Comment: Thank you for reply. I can understand why size of encrypted value is different. I overlooked "marshal dump"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple layers to what is happening here, and you cannot explain it solely on the data size + encryption used (ie you have to factor in the transformations that happen also)

Look at: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/29be3f5d8386fc9a8a67844fa9b7d6860574e715/activesupport/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb

and after that look at:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/29be3f5d8386fc9a8a67844fa9b7d6860574e715/activesupport/lib/active_support/message_verifier.rb which is used in the encryptor.

There are a few stages:

1. serializing the data you pass in (this is done using Marshal.dump if you don't specify any serializer)
2. base64 encoding the data.
3. generating a digest (ie signature) for the data.
4. encrypting the data+digest and storign the result + iv from the cipher used in encrypted form.

If you want to understand the generated encrypted data you basically need to trace through the code above, but:

```
 ::Base64.strict_encode64(Marshal.dump(1)).size is 8
 ::Base64.strict_encode64(Marshal.dump(10000)).size is 8
 ::Base64.strict_encode64(Marshal.dump(1000000000000000000000000000)).size is 24
```

But:

```
  Marshal.dump(1).size is 4
  Marshal.dump(10000).size is 6
  Marshal.dump(1000000000000000000000000000).size is 17
```

Here is how Marshal.dump works internally: http://jakegoulding.com/blog/2013/01/15/a-little-dip-into-rubys-marshal-format/

Here is how base64 encoding works: https://blogs.oracle.com/rammenon/entry/base64_explained Look at the rules for padding.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I can understand!!